# Show Mail in Django Application

Tags: html, email, django

I want to display an email in a django application.

The emails are stored in a maildir structure in the file system.

I don't want to reinvent this, but could not find any package which does this.

This question is only about displaying an mail.

It is not about sending or fetching mails.

Features which I would like to have:

- support HTML mails. Strip "dangerous" JS stuff
- show images inline
- allow downloading attachments (for example pdf files)
- Support nesting: Show emails containing emails

Comment: What do you mean by "maildir structure"?

Comment: @KevinBrown with "maildir" I mean this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maildir